# Apache Ignite: make clients to go to Ignite server on local machine instead of any machine in cluster

Tags: java, ignite

I have two Linux boxes, each of them hosts Ignite server instance which are linked into cluster of two nodes. Both servers have some caches with data ,caches are configured as `REPLICATED`.
Also each Linux box has about 15 Java processes that have Ignite client and connect to Ignite cluster to get some data.

Is it possible to configure Ignite clients in such way that they will first try to get data from cache which is running in Ignite server which is on the same Linux box as Ignite client? If there is no such server then go to any other active Ignite server in cluster.

I've tried `AffinityFunction` but it doesn't have information about Ignite client.

Comment: Are they thick or thin clients? (Affinity function affects how data is distributed around your cluster. For a replicated cache, where all your data is on every node, that's not going to have much effect.)

Comment: They are thick clients.

Answer (score 0):

Thick client will try to go where data is. If data is on collocated node then it will be queried. Of course for SQL or Scan queries it is not always possible to know, in this case query will be broadcast.

Comment: I use cache in `REPLICATED` mode which means that every server mode has full set of data.

Comment: I think it will go where primary partition is. Of course you can e.g. run closures on "local" node and do local gets on that node.